# Pushing one cv::Mat into another is going to copy it?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, matrix

I have a `std::vector<cv::Mat> descriptors` where `descriptor[i]` is the descriptors matrix of the `i-th` image of my dataset.

If I'm going to do:

```
cv::Mat descriptorsMat;
for(const auto mat : descriptors)
    descriptorsMat.push_back(mat);
```

is it going to *copy* `mat` at the end of `descriptorsMat` (which is inefficient both in time and memory) or is it going to add a *reference* of `mat` at the end of `descriptorsMat` (which is efficient, but could be considered unsafe)?

**WHY I NEED THIS:** since I'm going to train a `VlGMM` from VLFeat with these descriptors matrix, I need to load all the data inside a `float *`. So once I obtain `descriptorsMat`, I'm going to do:

```
if(!descriptorsMat.isContinous()){
    std::err<<"Descriptor matrix not continuous!"<<std::endl;
    return 1;
}
float *data = new float[descriptorsMat.total()];
std::memcpy(data,descriptorsMat.data,descriptorsMat.total() * sizeof(float));
```

If you have any better alternative solution, please post it!

Comment: It's going to perform a copy, yes.

Comment: This is a bad news. I think that the only solution then is carefully concatenate `std::memcopy` on `data` for each element in `descriptors`

Comment: `std::memcpy` isn't better than a memberwise copy.

Comment: Mmmmh sicne I'm not going to use `descriptors` anymore, what about `push_back(std::move(descriptors[i]))`?

Comment: I think that moving `descriptors[i]` is going to be more efficient, both in time and space. The question is: `push_back` from `cv::Mat` implements perfect forwarding?

Comment: It's STL, of course it does.

Comment: that's wrong. it is copying a Mat object but not the data. The Mat object is similar to a smart pointer, it's reference counting the data references. To deep copy the Mat data you have to call mat.clone or mat.copyTo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will only copy the Mat object which is some kind of header or smart pointer to the actual data elements.

```
cv::Mat descriptorsMat; 
for(const auto mat : descriptors)
      descriptorsMat.push_back(mat);
```

it is copying a Mat object but not the data. The Mat object is similar to a smart pointer, it's reference counting the data references. To deep copy the Mat data you have to call mat.clone or mat.copyTo

Comment: This might be the case for assignment, but push_back() will actually do a [deep copy](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp#L821)

Comment: @s1h push_back will copy the object, but the object in this case (cv::Mat) isn't much more than a smart pointer.

Comment: Could you  please give a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38512158/image-retrieval-through-fisher-vectors-why-my-implementation-works-so-bad) question?